# Get month from 2015-02-11 16:27:00

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I tried to get the month from the following date `2015-02-11 16:27:00`
 using getMonth() method,but throwing this error `:getMonth is not a function(…)`.Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add your complete code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var given_date = '2015-02-11 16:27:00';
var date = new Date(given_date);
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
alert(month);
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help.

```
var date = new Date("2015-02-11 16:27:00");

var monthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "long" }).format;
var longName = monthName(date); // "February"
var numericMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "numeric" }).format;
var intMonth = numericMonth(date); // 2
var shortMonthName = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { month: "short" }).format;
var shortName = shortMonthName(date); // "Feb"
alert(shortName);
```

You can learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console;TypeError: Date is not a function(…)

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the month number, then try this:

```
var str = "2015-02-11 16:27:00";
str = str.substring(5,7);
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code,

Convert your date to JavaScript date

```js
    var dt=new Date("2015-02-11 16:27:00");

    console.log(dt.getMonth()+1);//This will return you month
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console;TypeError: Date is not a function(…)

Comment: @forgottofly, which browser you are using??

Comment: @forgottofly, Check if you are writing correctly, Date is the javascripts inbuilt method, Here is the ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date("2015-02-11 16:27:00"); 
console.log(date.getMonth());
```

prints "1" for me. That is correct because [months starts from 0](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp).

Comment: so it should be: console.log(date.getMonth()+1);